# How can I resolve an issue where a Protractor test hangs indefinitely?

Tags: javascript, selenium, jasmine, protractor

I am running into an issue where a test case that I previously ran and I know is working, is now getting stuck indefinitely when it is executed. This occurs every time the test clicks a specific element. The test just hangs and is unable to continue with the script. No error occurs besides a timeout error. When I run the test I get the regular prompts:

```
[11:58:20] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[11:58:20] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
Started
A Jasmine spec timed out. Resetting the Webdriver Control Flow.
F

Failures:
1) clicks menu buttons
Message:
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
Stack:
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)

1 spec, 1 failure
Finished in 3000.147 seconds
[12:48:47] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of Webdriver still running
[12:48:47] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[12:48:47] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[12:48:47] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Then it just hangs there until it reaches the timeout I set. The following is a copy of the config and part of the testing script I am using.

config.js

```
 exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    directConnect: true,
    //getPageTimeout: timeout_in_millis
    // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
    capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
    //'browserName': 'firefox'

    },

    //suites:{},

    specs: ['basic_testing.js'],

    allScriptsTimeout: 3000000,

   //framework: 'jasmine2',
    onPrepare: function() { 
                browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
    var jasmineReporters = require('jasmine-reporters');
    jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new jasmineReporters.JUnitXmlReporter({
        consolidateAll: true,
        savePath: 'testresults',
        filePrefix: new Date().toJSON().substring(0,10).replace(/-/g , "")  + '_xmloutput'
    }))
},
    //Options to be passed to Jasmine.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
       defaultTimeoutInterval: 3000000
    }
};
```

basic_testing.js

```
describe('menu page', function()
{
    it('clicks menu buttons', function()
    {
        element(by.id("nav-group-ServiceOrders")).click();

        element(by.id("nav-item-Dashboard")).click();

        //This element is clicked but then the test hangs here
        element(by.id("nav-item-OrdersConsole")).click();

        element(by.id("nav-item-PersonnelConsole")).click();

        element(by.id("nav-item-PriorityPoints")).click();

    });
});
```

Comment: Can you include your spec file and config file in the question. With the current state its too difficult to identify root cause and its too vague

Comment: @J. Chang  what do you get in selenium server window when it hangs? does it show any error or any other info?

Comment: @AdityaReddy I added a copy of the config and test case

Comment: @user1207289 the there is no error that pops except just the timeout. I can edit the file and show what else it says as I am currently running it.

Comment: @J. Chang can you try this `describe('menu page', function()
{
    it('clicks menu buttons', function(done)
    {
      ....done(); }) ; }) ;`

Comment: @user1207289 its still not going through the test.

Comment: Why do you call `.all()` on an ID element?  Shouldn't there only be one?  also why are you using `browser()` as a way to click?  Just call `.click()` on the `input` variable you created

Comment: For the `.all()` case I am using a library that was made by the previous tester that has a function that would take different locators other than ID and it would execute them like that. Since that was how it was executed like that in the function that's how I showed it here. As far as just calling `.click()` on the `input` it was not performing the actual click on the desired element when we were using it.

Comment: @J. Chang you can call `click()` directly on  `element` like `element(by.id('yourID')).click();` . `element` object is ready to use in protractor as `browser` object

Comment: @user1207289 also try to  increase `defaultTimeoutInterval: 3000000` and run again

Comment: @user1207289 thank but the increase in the `defaultTimeoutInterval` didn't help. My issue is not with the timeout though. My problem is the fact that once I click on a certain element, for some reason the test just stops going through the script. It stays running but it won't execute any thing.

Comment: Also I understand that the way this test case is written is weird but it is based off of a library that I was given. Whether its written as I have it or as others have recommended, it finds all the elements I want it to find but it still does not help with the issue of the test case just stopping when I click a certain element. I thank you all for the feedback though..

Comment: @J.Chang - I'm also of the opinion that you may want to try the plain vanilla Protractor way - i.e. `element(by.id('nav-item-OrdersConsole')).click();`  At least we can see if this makes a difference in terms of the hanging issue.

Comment: Was not trying to come off stubborn or anything just had it done this way and the other ways before and the problem was the same. Retried it again in the vanilla way and the problem still persists. Updated the code to reflect it.

Comment: @J. Chang is your page publicly accessible? if not , attach the html. somehow. its difficult to help you unless someone see the html

Comment: does your page has continuous $http polling which keeps protractor waiting for Angular to finish. I suspect that could be the root cause

Comment: @user1207289 sorry but I gave all the information I was allowed to share.

Comment: @AdityaReddy I think you are right. I'm still a little new to protractor so I am not entirely sure if its related to your comment but when I implemented a `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` the test case worked perfectly fine again.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already explored [Timeouts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#timeouts) and still facing problem then
use `browser.executeScript('window.stop();');` if the resulting page after click on first element loaded your second element to be clicked but taking to time to load all elements in a page then to stop further load of elements and proceed with click on second element. your code would be something like below.

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
1stElement.click();
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(2ndElement), 5000);
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(2ndElement), 5000);
browser.executeScript('window.stop();');
2ndElement.click();
```